# How to sub-number tables in the tabular mode?

Tags: tables, math-mode, numbering, subcaption

I want the first table to be 1 (a) and the second table to be 1 (b) [instead of Table 1 and Table 2] without changing the `{center}` or the `{tabular}` environment. Alternate cells are merged. Is it possible to do that please?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{-5pt}
\begin{tabular}{ | m{6.85cm} | m{6.7cm} | }
  \hline
  \centering
  \textbf{heading 1} & \textbf{heading 2} \\  
  \hline
  1 \\
  \hline
  $$ eq. 1a $$ & $$ eq. 1b $$ \\ 
  \hline
  2 \\
  \hline
  $$ 2a $$  & $$ eq. 2b $$ \\ 
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Table 1\label{t1}}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{-5pt}
\begin{tabular}{ | m{6.75cm} | m{6.75cm} | }
  \hline
  \centering
  \textbf{heading 1} & \textbf{heading 2} \\  
  \hline
  3 \\
  \hline
  $$ eq. 3a $$ & $$ eq. 3b $$\\ 
  \hline
  4 \\
  \hline
  $$ eq. 4a $$ & $$ eq. 4b $$ \\ 
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Table 2\label{t2}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the `subcaption` package